# Регулярное выражение для почты и логина

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, делаю регистрацию и знаю, что есть функция `preg_match();`, а вот как установить проверку не знаю.

Помогите сделать проверку на следующее:

1. E-mail (ну простой формат test@test.ru)
2. Логин (Английский буквы и цифры)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
// Email
$pattern = '/^[\w\d_.+-]+@[\w\d-]+.[\w]+$/';
$str = 'info@domain.com';
if(preg_match($pattern, $str)) echo 'Валидно<br />';
else  echo 'Не валидно<br />';
// Login
$pattern = '/^[a-z\d]+$/i';
$str = 'login432';
if(preg_match($pattern, $str)) echo 'Валидно<br />';
else  echo 'Не валидно<br />';
```

Следует учитывать, что регулярное выражение для электронного адреса приблизительное, учесть все ньюансы электронной почты довольно трудно (возможно будет пропускать некоторые экзотические случаи).

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html так примерно выглядит правильная регулярка?

Comment: @pavel, ага, но по-моему даже RFC822 устарел (нужно проверять).

Comment: Для электропочты я бы проверил так `^[^\x00-\x1f\s]+@[^\x00-\x1f\s]+$`. Все равно без подтверждения через письмо она не имеет ни какого смысла.